# What determines the normalized form of a Unicode string in C++?

Tags: c++, unicode

When creating string literals in C++, I would like to know how the strings are encoded  -- I can specify the encoding form (UTF-8, 16, or 32), but I want to know how the compiler determines the unspecified parts of the encoding.

For UTF-8 the byte-ordering is not relevant, and I would assume the byte ordering of UTF-16 and UTF-32 is, by default, the system byte-ordering.  This leaves the normalization.  As an example:

```
std::string u8foo = u8"Föo";
std::u16string u16foo = u"Föo";
std::u32string u32foo = U"Föo";
```

In all three cases, there are at least two possible encodings -- decomposed or composed.   For more complex characters there might by multiple possible encodings, but I would assume that the compiler would generate one of the normalized forms.

Is this a safe assumption?  Can I know in advance in what normalization the text in `u8foo` and `u16foo` is stored?  Can I specify it somehow?

I am of the impression this is not defined by the standard, and that it is implementation specific.  How does GCC handle it?  Other compilers?

Comment: UTF 8, 16, 32 are encodings, string can have different normalization form regardless encoding.

Comment: Your text editor ought to take a stab at it.

Comment: The Unicode standard defines normalization. In fact, there are four different normalization forms. But this has nothing to do with your piece of code, which is simply what it is.

Comment: C++ make no guarantees about normalizing Unicode strings. Although it depends on the compiler, I'd guess that the three strings will have the same normalization (or not) as was left by the text editor with which the code was created.

Comment: @Kerrek SB:  On execution, the strings are stored in the variables, one would hope in one of the defined normalization forms.  The question is which form is created.  I've attempted to clarify the text.

Comment: I suspect in all cases you're violating the spec. You're using string literals that don't have encoding/type prefixes, so they're narrow strings by default. It also means that C++ won't be looking for encoded characters most likely and may just pick up "whatever the editor saved as" as the data. It looks like [gcc accept a flag to specify the encoding for a file](/questions/6794590/how-does-file-encoding-affect-c11-string-literals), but even so, I'm fairly sure narrow strings containing non-ASCII characters are not going to be well-defined. Use `u8`, `u` and `U` prefixes properly.

Comment: For reference: [Docs on string literal prefixes for C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)

Comment: @ShadowRanger: I modified the code sample.  At least in GCC there's no problem with writing "std::string foo = "Föo" -- by default GCC uses the system locale if it can -- since my system locale is Unicode, I get a UTF-8 encoded string.  I just don't know what guarentees I have about normalization.    The u16 and u32 examples are compiler errors however.  So good infos, but not what I'm trying to find out.

Comment: If you want them to be normalized to have to normalize them yourself. Otherwise you have to assume that they are not normalized.

Comment: AFAICT, with `g++` and a default locale encoding of `utf-8` (with the editor saving in that form and `gcc/g++` assuming that encoding), it's converting from the source file's `utf-8` encoding to the encoding matching the prefix for each interned string literal. So `u8"Föo"` is `46 c3 b6 6f 00`, `u"Föo"` is `46 00 f6 00 6f 00 00 00` and `U"Föo"` is `46 00 00 00 f6 00 00 00 6f 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`. I see no indication of any unusual normalization; it's storing the Unicode ordinals without any sort of decomposition, in system dependent endianness.

Comment: @ShadowRanger:  "without any sort of decomposition" would indicate NFC (normal form composed) or NFKC (Compatibility Composition).  But the question here is really "what is the usual normalization?".   I would hope that the editor used wouldn't have any impact on the encoding (actual encoding, not encoding form), but I'm finding it hard to get a determinative answer.

Comment: @spacemoose: there is no definitive answer, because the standard allows implementation-defined behaviour. But gcc does not alter the codepoint sequence. If you give it a UTF-8 sequence surrounded by double-quotes, *whether normalized or not*, that's what you get.

Comment: @rici That's why I didn't specify a codepoint sequence in the example.  I want to know what the behavior is when I initalize a string  with a string literal as shown.  The question has been modified in an attempt to make it clearer.

Comment: @spacemoose: But you do specify a codepoint sequence. The string you insert in the source code is composed of concrete bytes encoding unicode codepoints, not abstract characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interpretation of character strings outside of the basic source character set is implementation-dependent. (Standard quote below.) So there is no definitive answer; an implementation is not even obliged to accept source characters outside of the basic set.

Normalisation involves a mapping of possibly multiple source codepoints to possibly multiple internal codepoints, including the possibility of reordering the source character sequence (if, for example, diacritics are not in the canonical order). Such transformations are more complex than the source→internal transformation anticipated by the standard, and I suspect that a compiler which attempted them would not be completely conformant. In any event, I know of no compiler which does so.

So, in general, you should ensure that the source code you provide to the compiler is normalized as per your desired normalization form, if that matters to you.

In the particular case of GCC, the compiler interprets the source according to the default locale's encoding, unless told otherwise (with the `-finput-charset` command-line option). It will recode if necessary to Unicode codepoints. But it does not alter the sequence of codepoints. So if you give it a normalized UTF-8 string, that's what you get. And if you give it an unnormalized string, that's also what you get.

In this [example on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e4c0c8c9a0e0af4), the first string is composed and the second one decomposed (although they are both in some normalization form). (The rendering of the second example string in coliru seems to be browser-dependent. On my machine, chrome renders them correctly, while firefox shifts the diacritics one position to the left. YMMV.)

---

The C++ standard defines the *basic source character set* (in §2.3/1) to be letters, digits, five whitespace characters (space, newline, tab, vertical tab and formfeed) and the symbols:

```
_ { } [ ] # ( ) < > % : ; . ? * + - / ^ & | ~ ! = , \ " ’
```

It gives the compiler a lot of latitude as to how it interprets the input, and how it handles characters outside of the basic source character set. §2.2 paragraph 1 (from C++14 draft n4527):

> Physical source file characters are mapped, in an implementation-defined manner, to the basic source character set (introducing new-line characters for end-of-line indicators) if necessary. The set of physical source file characters accepted is implementation-defined. Any source file character not in the basic source character set (2.3) is replaced by the universal-character-name that designates that character. (An implementation may use any internal encoding, so long as an actual extended character encountered in the source file, and the same extended character expressed in the source file as a universal-character-name (e.g., using the \uXXXX notation), are handled equivalently except where this replacement is reverted in a raw string literal.)

It's worth adding that diacritics are *characters*, from the perspective of the C++ standard. So the composed ñ (\u00d1) is one character and the decomposed ñ (\u006e \u0303) is two characters, regardless of how it looks to you.

A close reading of the above paragraph from the standard suggests that normalization or other transformations which are not strictly 1-1 are not permitted, although the compiler may be able to reject an input which contains characters outside the basic source character set.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual C++ will keep the normalization used in the source file.

The main problem you have when doing this cross-platform is making sure the compilers are using the right encodings. Here is how MSVC handles it:

#### Source file encoding

The compiler has to read your source file with the right encoding.

MSVC doesn't have an option to specify the encoding on the command line but relies on the BOM to detect encoding, so it can read the following encodings:

- UTF-16 with BOM, if the file starts with that BOM
- UTF-8, if the file starts with `"\xef\xbb\xbf"` (the UTF-8 "BOM")
- in all other cases, the file is read using an ANSI code page dependent on your system language setting. In practice this means you can only use ASCII characters in your source files.

#### Output encoding

Your unicode strings will be encoded with some encoding before written to your executable as a byte string.

Wide literals (`L"..."`) are always written as UTF-16.

MSVC 2010 you can use `#pragma execution_character_set("utf-8")` to have `char` strings encoded as UTF-8. By default they are encoded in your local code page. That pragma is apparently missing from MSVC 2012 but it's back in MSVC 2013.

```
#pragma execution_character_set("utf-8")

const char a[] = "ŦεŞŧ";
```

Support for the Unicode literals (`u"..."` and friends) [was only just now introduced with MSVC 2015](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx).